# stop animation from another activity

Tags: android

I have an activity there i have a menu icon, when i press the icon an animation start, this is to show some feedback when the data is loading, so i want to stop the animation when the app stop syncing the data, the problem is that in TabActivity i start the animation and in MyHandler i manage the syncing progress

Here i start the animation (BaseActivity):

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.sync_anim);
            animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            findViewById(R.id.update_data).startAnimation(animation);

            Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.sync_anim);

            findViewById(R.id.update_data).startAnimation(a);
```

here is when the data finish syncing (MyHandler):

```
                @Override
            public void run() {

                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                String str = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",java.util.Locale.getDefault()).format(calendar.getTime());
                str = "2015-08-01";
                MyHandler.this.context.getSharedPreferences("DateTime",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("user_time", str).commit();


                if ((n > 100) && (n < 200)) {                                           
                    Log.e("MyHandler", "100 200");
                    MyApplication.CloseLoadingProgress();

                    String strtoShowToast = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy",java.util.Locale.getDefault()).format(calendar.getTime());
                    Globals.lastUpdateDate = strtoShowToast;
                    MyHandler.this.context.getSharedPreferences("DateTime",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("user_time", new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",java.util.Locale.getDefault()).format(calendar.getTime())).commit();
                    Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getInstance(),
                                    context.getResources().getString(R.string.bluetooth_updateDataNow)+" "+strtoShowToast,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Comment: You could use [`EventBus`](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) for it

Answer (score 0):

The solution was sending a broadcast receiver on MyHandler and receive it on my BaseActivity